# Magento Store Views Not showing up

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, store-view

I'm trying to create a new store view for my Store. 
When I added the store view, the following is the result.

[image: screenshot1]

After this I cleared my cache and reindexed the data.

Now When I navigate to System >> Configuration, I don't find the new store view in the list.
The following screenshot explains.

[image: screenshot2]

Any thoughts on why this happens?

Running Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: I have tested this on a clean Magento install and could not reproduce the problem.